Vmware PowerCLI: How to use Invoke-VMScript to run command in PowerShell with elevated admin privileges
I want to execute a command on one of the VMs remotely using the Invoke-VMScript cmdlet. I want to run it with elevated admin privileges (in the remote VM) where the ScriptText will execute, but it throws the following error.
Command:
Invoke-VMScript -ScriptText ' Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList "-c", "whoami" -verb RunAs ' -VM 'TEST-VM4105' -GuestUser 'username' -GuestPassword 'password' -Verbose

Error:
ScriptOutput
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: This operation requires an interactive window station.
|  At line:1 char:5
|  + & { Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList "-c", "whoami" -verb RunAs ...
|  +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
|      + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
|      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
|
|
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Is there any simple or difficult way to achieve this ?

right click the PS shortcut and select Run As Admin.  Then run cmdlet.

:) The question is: How can we remotely invoke a script on a VMware VM using Invoke-VMScript with the session running in elevated privileges in the remote VM?

You need an account with Admin Privilege.  The account has to be recognized on both local and remote machines.  In a corporate network Group Policy would be used.  The admin privilege would automatically be passed when the connection is made between the local and remote machines.  The guest user would be user to run the script (impersonate the guest user).  Impersonation requires an Admin to run the script.

-GuestUser 'username' >>> this user is part of Administrator group

Doesn't matter.  The script is run in account that is logged in.  Then you are impersonating -GuestUser 'username'
